# Is it faster to use a bool and return later or call function and return immediately? C++

Tags: c++

I have a question, which method would be theoretically faster to run? I have an extremely CPU intensive function, which doesn't run under certain conditions. Basically what I'm asking is, is it faster to just copy the calling code that uses many arguments many times in the same function, or is it faster to just use a bool to make the assembly smaller? Thanks

```
bool ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction = false;

if (!somefunction())
{
    ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction = true;
}
else if (!somefunction2())
{
    ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction = true;
}
else if (!somefunction3())
{
    ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction = true;
}
else if (!somefunction4())
{
    ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction = true;
}

if (!ShouldNotDoExpensiveFunction)
{
    return RunExpensiveFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
else
{
     return RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
}

or


if (!somefunction())
{
    return RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
}
else if (!somefunction2())
{
    return RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
}
else if (!somefunction3())
{
    return RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
}
else if (!somefunction4())
{
    return RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
}
else
{
    return RunExpensiveFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

Comment: You can use [Compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org) to see the assembly. Other than that, you should just benchmark.

Comment: Assuming the arguments for the in-expensive call remain the same, you could reduce the code by using logical or. Anyway, using bool s won't necessarily reduce the assembly output and even if it did, volume of assembly code is a terrible performance metric. If it really is super important that this code be optimal, just profile since different solutions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both snippets are likely to have comparable performance. Since your function is very CPU intensive, the potential marginal difference between these approaches is very likely to be insignificant. A compiler might even generate identical assembly for each.

The former is superior to the latter not because of performance reasons, but because you avoid repeating the arguments thereby making the code less fragile to change.

There is an even better approach that doesn't require any repetition:

```
return somefunction() && somefunction2() && somefunction3() && somefunction4()
    ? RunExpensiveFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    : RunInexpensiveFunction(1, 2);
```